# How to do a clear database design

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database.

On my system, users can do this:

1. Sent message to other users with text and/or files (images, videos, etc.)
2. Sent a friendship request to other users without any text.

I thought that messages and friendship request are the same (a friendship request is a type of message):

[image]

But, I think I can split that table into two tables, to make my model more clear:

[image]

**What is your opinion? One or two tables?**

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a huge user base use one table, because the join operation is very consuming. But for the elegancy of it I'd say two tables.
By the way, friendship is one word. a friend ship is a ship that is a friend :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand this: "because the join operation is very consuming". Which tables am I going to join?